# How to change author in Subversion

Tags: svn

I have created a new Subversion (`svn`) branch and imported unversioned files and checkin, however I notice when I do `svn log`, I still see the author as the person who owned the trunk and left the company.

How do I change the "Author" to have my names for the files I'm checking in?

Here is how it looks like. My name is Dan:

```
    r4146 | kelly | 2012-03-20 14:17:16 -0400 (Tue, 20 Mar 2012) | 1 line
    
    dan14: Correct hardcoded path
```

Comment: is 4146 revision a revision done by you?

Comment: Do you work on Kelly's workstation?

Comment: Good point; No , here is how it is . we all logon to unix with our user and then do a sudo <common user> and work here and check-in.

Comment: when I say commit, it still get the author as kelly. Not sure why.

Comment: Yes 4146 revision is acutally done by me and you could see it still shows "kelly". I just did `svn commit -m "dan14: Correct hardcoded path" <filename>`.

Comment: `sudo <common user>` ??? nightmare!!! If all use *single user* always -  all use **saved credentials of this user** also. And common workflow seems, well... strange. Why not local WorkingCopy without authorization headache?!

Comment: When I say All, I donot mean all the developers. This is not the copy which developer use it. They have a seperate branch to work on which they can commit with their user. Esp this branch which only can be worked with <common user> and check-in the files.

Comment: may be the word <common> is confusing, but it not really common and user but a with sudo previleages. Only the user belongs to a group will have access to SSH env.

Comment: I think this is what I need. `http://home.introweb.nl/d/dodger/svnauthor.html`

Comment: Yes, and future commits perform with --username USER --password PASS options added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a google a bit and found a link which helps resolve the problem [Setting SVN Author](http://home.introweb.nl/d/dodger/svnauthor.html)

Comments from @Lazy Badger  `Yes, and future commits perform with --username USER --password PASS options added.`

Answer (score -1):

This is because you copied the revision history along with it. That's the normal behaviour. If you want to get rid of the revision history and only see the last, or last few revisions, which you made, then play around with the "-r" option. If you never did a commit then first do a commit and then do a copy from that revision:

```
-r [--revision] ARG      : ARG (some commands also take ARG1:ARG2 range)
                            A revision argument can be one of:
                             NUMBER       revision number
                             '{' DATE '}' revision at start of the date
                             'HEAD'       latest in repository
                             'BASE'       base rev of item's working copy
                             'COMMITTED'  last commit at or before BASE
                             'PREV'       revision just before COMMITTED
```